# How to extract numbers from a string without regex?

Tags: python, string, list

I would like to extract all the numbers contained in a string. I can't use regex, is there any other way?

Example:userVariable = "someTextWithNumbers432andTextwith331"

Result:[432,331]

Comment: Of course there is another way... scan the string and extract the digits...etc. Show your efforts.

Comment: As @trincot suggested earlier and do a loop - using `ch.isdigit()`

Comment: how? Have I been trying for two days?

Comment: @TsignadzeGiorgi, why you can't use regex?

Comment: *"I have been trying..."*: please show what you tried and what goes wrong.

Comment: Some sample snippets below for your learning.  Check out.

Comment: updated the solution to return  [432,331].  hope it answers the question.  I'm curious though, why not regex. if don't mind.  thanks

Comment: When using this forum, it's best practice to show your work along with the errors.  It will give contributors a better understanding and help debug the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this would be to create an empty list and a temporary string variable, then to loop through the letters in the string. For each iteration, you check if the current character is a digit. If it is, append it to to the temporary string. If it isn't, check if the temp string is empty. If it's empty, do nothing. If there's a value in the temp string (say, '1345'), add the temp string value to the list and reset the value of the temp string back to ''. You'll need to make sure you handle the edge case where there's a number in the temporary string when the loop ends also so you don't have an incomplete list.

Here's some pseudocode:

```
list = []
temp = ''

for char in string {
    if char is digit {
        append char to temp
    }
    else {
        if temp != '' {
            append temp to list
            temp = ''
        }
    }
}

if temp != '' {
    append temp to list
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this `groupby` from itertools.  Please ask if you have any question.

```
from itertools import groupby
s = "your long string"

for k, g in groupby(s, key=lambda ch: ch.isdigit()):
    if k: print(''.join(list(g)))   # you can use result.append() here too
```

#### second illustration:

```
result = []
 
>>> for k, g in groupby(s, key=lambda ch: ch.isdigit()):
        if k: result.append(int(''.join(list(g))))  # convert the joined digits to integer
>>> print(result)
[432, 331]
```

Comment: `key=str.isdigit` would less redundant

Answer (score 0):

Why not regex though? here is one way

```
string="".join([x if (x.isdigit()) else " " for x in list(string)]
              ).strip().replace(' ',',',1
                       ).replace(' ','')
print("Result:", [int(i) for i in string.split(',')])
```

```
Result: [432, 331]
```

Comment: Result:[ 432, 331]

Comment: i want two separated strings

Comment: @TsignadzeGiorgi, updated the solution

Comment: @DanielHao, updated the solution